# php не меняется часы/месяц/год в функции

Tags: php

Имеется следующий код:

```
<?php
$date = date("y-m-d h:m:s");
echo $date;
?>
```

Почему то при обновлении меняются секунды, но не меняются минуты, и часы.

Comment: А вы пробовали обновить страницу через минуты/часы/дни/месяцы/годы?

Comment: А минута прошла перед новым обновлением?

Comment: Да дададададададада

Comment: @ОнотолЕ, вы ведь знаете, что регистр символов в аргументе функции `date` имеет значение? `m` (строчная M) это **порядковый номер месяца** с ведущим нулем!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что [документация](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).
Вы используете `m` и для месяца и для минуты.

```
$date = date("y-m-d h:i:s");
echo $date;
```

Comment: `Y-m-d H:i:s` **H** и **Y** заглавная

Comment: @mix, h - 12 часовой формат. H - 24 часовой формат. Перейдите по ссылке в ответе.